# I find indexing in python for numpy array weird

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I'm quite new to python and I'm working on some data manipulation. 
I thought the indexing in numpy would be [row][column], but it's not what I see when I execute in python. 
Below is a simple example of how python is behaving. I don't understand why I get the same results for the last two commands:

```
import numpy as num

test_arr = num.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],dtype=num.float32)

test_arr[0][:]
array([1., 2., 3.], dtype=float32)

test_arr[:][0]
array([1., 2., 3.], dtype=float32)
```

I would expect

```
test_arr[0][:]
array([1., 2., 3.], dtype=float32)

test_arr[:][0]
array([1., 4., 7.], dtype=float32)
```

Can someone explain why python behaves as it does and how to get the 0th index of all rows?

Comment: Even with Python lists `[:]` only creates a copy; with arrays it's a view.  So it's doing nothing in your examples.  Each `[]` is a separate indexing step.  Take time to read numpy basics, such as this indexing page: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

to get a column in numpy array use `[:,n]` where `n` is your column number

```
test_arr[:,0]
array([1., 4., 7.], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In  : import numpy as num

In  : test_arr = num.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],dtype=num.float32)

In  : test_arr[0,:]
Out : [1. 2. 3.]

In  : test_arr[:,0]
Out : [1. 4. 7.]
```